# Get all the user input with EOF?

Tags: c++, input, eof

I'm having problems getting all the user input from the terminal. It's always one line short, and it's the last line.

```
do{
    getline(std::cin, input);
    buffer += input;
    buffer += '\n';
}while(!input.empty());
```

gives me the desired output, but it ends when I press Enter, and I want it to end when it reaches End Of File(EOF), when i press Ctrl+D. I have tried

```
while(!(std::cin >> input).eof()){
    buffer += input;
    buffer += '\n';
}
```

but it doesn't get the last line. Adding the input to the buffer after the while-loop also doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Keep reading input with [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
std::string buffer;
std::string input;

while (std::getline(std::cin, input))
{
    buffer += input;
    buffer += '\n';
}
```

When you input `EOF` `getline` [will set `eofbit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) and the loop will end.

In any case the second snippet should store the last input as well.

Comment: I believe this also  adds a new line after the input is done, correct? And if so, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @r3k0j There are several ways to ignore remaining `\n` on the buffer, one of them is to use `cin.ignore()`.

Comment: looks like std::cin >> input doesn't save the input format. For example space characters are turned into new line characters. and cin.ignore() somehow doesn't save the first character of the other lines expect the first one.

Comment: @r3k0j `cin` stops at white space, meaning it reads word by word, as opposed to `getline` which reads the whole line until `\n`, I had a feeling you needed the whole line, so I removed that part from my comment.

Comment: @r3k0j inside de loop you don't need `cin.ignore`, `getline` ignores it by itself, I was talking about the last input, after the loop, a `\n` will reamain in the input buffer, so if you want to remove that last one use a `cin.ignore` after the loop. Inside the loop you don't need anything else, I remind you that you are adding a`\n` to `buffer` (`buffer += '\n';`).

Comment: that really helped, thanks. i almost have achieved, what i wanted to do, expect one last thing. i actually get one character more that what I'm supposed to. Any idea why? if you want to see the code you can check my last question

Comment: @r3k0j what character is that? You need to be more specific. A newline character is needed at the end of each line  for getline to read the input buffer, it's the terminator character.you can specify a different terminator character by passing it as 3rd argument of getline, you can check that out in the getline documentation I linked above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244590/discussion-between-r3k0j-and-anastaciu).